# Magento "static block" wrapper

Tags: php, magento

I swear I've looked at dozens of questions... maybe I'm just losing it.

I want to modify the static block "wrappers" - the divs with class "block" in Magento in the phtml files. Is there a static block controller of some sort, or are they all built completely separately? And if so, where can I find one as an example?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be a little bit more descriptive?   Which blocks are you trying to modify?  Header?  Footer?  Each has their own phtml files.  Also there are certain "content" blocks that must be modified in the admin section.  a little more info?

Comment: @Zak Certainly! They're labeled, in the default install, as `block block-list block-compare` or `block block-cart`, they are default right column-blocks on the install as well.

Comment: OK ... Those are all going to be separate PHTML files. Since I can't see your exact installation, for those blocks enabling `template path hints` will get you to the phtml files you need.  If you need help enabling path hints, look here --> http://www.redlightblinking.com/blog/magento-tutorials/magento-debugging-how-to-debug-template-paths-logging-and-display-errors  That will get you started, then you'll be in the right "area" to make the changes you need.

Comment: @Zak Wish that was an answer I could +1! That's awesome! Haven't played with Magento in a while, but I never knew about that for the 10 or so sites I've built out with it. Man, that's handy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items like `block block-list block-compare` or `block block-cart` are all going to be separate PHTML files. Since I can't see your exact installation, for those blocks enabling template path hints will get you to the phtml files you need. If you need help enabling path hints, look here [Enable Path Hints](http://www.redlightblinking.com/blog/magento-tutorials/magento-debugging-how-to-debug-template-paths-logging-and-display-errors) That will get you started, then you'll be in the right "area" to make the changes you need.